# How would I build a content area with cards in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I’m teaching myself Wordpress and have gotten really far. I have one last section to build out. I’m not quite sure how to build it out. I’m using bootstrap as the framework and I want the client to be able to add multiple cards if needed.

I thought I could use the Advanced Custom Fields. But I didn’t see an option where I could have a repeating block that would stay in two columns.

Ahhh I couldn't post my image =(

Basically I need to know how to build a content section with cards that are in two columns in wordpress. It is not global.

Any help or point in the right direction would be great!!
 Thanks so much!

Comment: Try using Advanced custom field PRO, Or buy the Repeater extension individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACF Pro has a repeater field, as noted here on the docs: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/. you should consider buying the PRO version or only this extension - it'd save you lots of time of development work.

that's some sample code taken from it:

```
<?php
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ):
    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ) : the_row();
        // display a sub field value
        the_sub_field('sub_field_name');
    endwhile;
else :
    // no rows found
endif;    
?>
```